# Seleccionar el nodo padre de un elemento con CSSS

Tags: html, css

El código que me han dado tiene elementos que se pintan dinámicamente, son informativos y están dentro de un `a`, quisiera saber cómo puedo, teniendo el id de un `div` que se encuentra dentro de este `a`, seleccionar  mediante CSS a ese  `a`.

```
<a href="x">
     <div id="z">
     </div>
</a>
```

Entonces, teniendo el `div #z`, ¿cómo hago para seleccionar el nodo que encapsula a este div mediante css?

Comment: En css no existe un selector de nodo padre como tal. Existen varias soluciones posible, bien que añadas directamente una clase css al elemento en cuestión, o bien que uses javascript para añadir la clase dinámicamente.

Comment: Como nota adicional, mencionar que el borrador de css4 incluye un pseudo selector `:has` que funcionaría para tu caso, pero a día de escribir este comentario, ningún navegador es compatible con ello. [:has selector MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Comment: Desde tu punto de vista (a)<--(div) tendrías que usar `JavaScript` / `jQuery` , ahora si quieres hacerlo a través de `CSS` tienes que verlo de otro punto de vista (a)-->(div).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo mediante CSS no se puede aún, supuestamente hay peticiones para que la actualización a la especificación incluya poder referenciar "hacia atrás", pero así como está ahora no se puede.
Entendiendo hacia atrás desde un hijo saber quien es el padre (una fatalidad genealógica, pero bueno....)

Si usas jQuery puedes posicionarte en un elemento y saber quien es su padre. Para ello tendrías que usar [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) , [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) , o [.parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)

También podrías usar [:parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/), pero tal como indica la documentación, es parte de jQuery y no de CSS.

Sin jQuery puedes usar la propiedad *parentElement* del objeto DOM (ref. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como acceder al elemento `<a>` desde `<div>` a traves del **id** y tambien un ejemplo de como acceder al elemento `<a>` a traves de una **clase**.

Ejemplo:

```js
// a traves del id:
el = document.getElementById("z").parentElement;

console.log(el);

// a traves de una clase:
el = document.getElementsByClassName("z");

console.log(el);
console.log(el.length);

for(i = 0; i <el.length; i++) {
 console.log(el[i]);
 console.log(el.item(i));
 console.log(el.namedItem(i));
}
```

```html
<a href="x" class="z">
     <div id="z">
     </div>
</a>
```